# Finding perimeter of a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> In triangle $ABC$,$AB=AC=28$ and $BC=20$.Points $D,E,F$ are on sides $AB$,$BC$ & $CA$ ,respectively,such that $DE$ & $EF$ is parallel to $AC$ & $AB$,respectively .What is the perimeter of the parallelogram $ADEF$?

I tried to find out any relation between $AD$ & $FC$,but failed.One time I thought about the area related property but I failed to find anyway.Somebody please give me some hint to do this.Thank you

[image]

Comment: if you write $BE=x$, you can find an expression for $DE$ and $FE$ in function of $x$ (by Thalès). Writing the perimeter, you may find out that $x$ disappear from the formula and it remains only 56.

Comment: @Evargalo please write the mathematical from of your statement.Please explain clearly

Comment: That was the difficult way. My non-analytic answer below is much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Show that BDE and EFC are isoceles
- Use it to write $AD+DE+EF+AF=AD+BD+AF+FC=AB+BC=56$

Comment: ohh !it was easy soft question.I don't think in that way .I don't saw that triangle ABC &BDE are similar.Thank you.You have done a grt job by doing this so quickly

Answer (score 0):

$56$ of course! We can calculate it by the following way:
$$AD+AF+FE+DE=2(AF+FE)=2AC=56.$$

Answer (score 0):

since $DE$ and $AC$,or $EF$ and $FC$ are parallels so $\triangle ABC,\triangle BDE,\triangle EFC$ are isosceles  triangles.$$\begin{cases} 28-x=y \\ 28-y=x \end{cases}\Rightarrow x+y=28$$
so perimetr is

> $${ P }_{ ADEF }=2\left( x+y \right) =56$$
>   [image]